# Avoid DataError on datagridview cell as Date when is empty

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have the next problem. I have a grid with two columns where column1 is formatted as Date, but sometimes these cells can be empty too because the user can edit them and empty is a valid value for my purpose.

But every time the user sends (pressing "Send" button) this information with emtpy cells DataError handler ( I use it for validating date format when exist something different to empty) is raised and the action is not performed.

Is there a way to avoid this situation?
Thanks  a lot!

Comment: You should write logic in handler for not to validate if input value is empty

Comment: Currently Im handling the error message (showing nothing) but anyway the send is not performed.

Comment: Without looking at your code very little can be suggested. Please share the relevant code

Comment: Give us code of `Send` button

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to solve it using these things:
e.Cancel = False
e.ThrowException = False
and also I set the cell value to Nothing.

Thanks!